# add_action hook fails to find declared function

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filter, hook

I am creating a WordPress plugin in which I need to track if any page in the front side is opened or any link is clicked?
I am sort of blank on this. Can anyone tell me what should I do to achieve this?

I tried this.

```
class WP_Adminmsp_Webservice{


    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', 'msp_pages_permalink', 10, 2 ); 
}

function msp_pages_permalink($permalink_structure, $post_id )
      {
        echo "called";
      }
}
```

This is showing this error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback function 'msp_pages_permalink' not found or invalid function name.

Comment: do you know what `add_action` does?

Comment: yes. That I know and have function msp_pages_permalink too

Comment: show us the code, then. :) at least the function declaration.

Comment: because it just seems that `msp_pages_permalink` is not really defined.

Comment: check the code now

Comment: where do you define your function? is it in the same file you have the `add_action`?

Comment: yes in the same plugin file.

Comment: Something is missing then. It should work, or at least not give you that error. But there is something in the code that you are not showing us that's breaking things down. Are you declaring a`namespace` by any chance?

Comment: class WP_Adminmsp_Webservice{ this is in the top of the code. in constructor add_action( 'init', 'msp_pages_permalink', 10, 2 );  is added

Comment: a **"small"** detail. show us an skeleton of your class, showing where are you running calling `add_action`.

Comment: check now the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When hooking an object method, you need to pass the object that contains the method to the `add_action` call (which in turn will use it for a `call_user_func` call).

E.g., assuming you are running the action from another method `inside` that object, you'd do:

```
add_action('init', [$this, 'your_method'],  10, 2 );
```

Where "your_method" is the name of the (**public**) method you need to call.

If you are calling `add_action` from *outside* the object, you would do something like:

```
$plugin_object = new My_Plugin();
add_action('init', [$plugin_object, "your_method"],  10, 2 )
```

Comment: let me try this out

Comment: ???? Please, try to be more mindful. If you don't post the code you need help with as it is, you just make people waste their time trying to help you, but it is simply no possible if you give us the **wrong** data. Post your code as it really is.

Comment: yeah. solved. 
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'msp_pages_permalink'), 10, 2 ); $this is what I missed